# Event listener callbacks still being duplicated when using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, google-publisher-tag

I'm in a muddle about React, useEffect, and adding callback functions to event listeners. These listeners being registered to Google Publisher Tag events, and I'm trying to get to the outcome where I can use parameters passed (`display` in my example code) and the event object in my callback function.

`````
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>````
`````

```
const { useEffect } = React;

const slotOnloadCallback = (display, event) => {
    const { slot } = event;
    console.log(`callback called for slot ${slot.getSlotElementId()} - display: ${display}`);
  };

const create = (id, display) => {
  window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
  window.googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    const slot = window.googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/example', [728, 90], id);
    slot.addService(googletag.pubads());
    window.googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    window.googletag.enableServices();
  });

  window.googletag.pubads().addEventListener("slotOnload", slotOnloadCallback.bind(null, display));

  window.googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    window.googletag.display(id);
  });
}

const Ad = (props) => {
  const { id, display } = props;
  console.log(`Ad ${id}: Rendering`);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Ad ${id}: Mounted`);
    create(id, display)
  }, []);
  return (
    <div id={id}></div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Ad 
        id="slot-1"
        display="full"
      />
      <p>...</p>
      <Ad
        id="slot-2"
        display="partial"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

The event listeners are working, but when I bind the variable I require to the callback, the callback ends up triggered multiple times (* the number of Ad components are rendered). I think I understand that binding variables to a function makes it unique, and therefore can be registered multiple times to one listener, but I thought that using useEffect got around this... :(

I am getting the output:

```
"Ad slot-1: Rendering"
"Ad slot-2: Rendering"
"Ad slot-1: Mounted"
"Ad slot-2: Mounted"
"callback called for slot slot-1 - display: full"
"callback called for slot slot-1 - display: partial"
"callback called for slot slot-2 - display: full"
"callback called for slot slot-2 - display: partial"
```

... Of which I'm confused about how `slot-1` is even receiving `partial`.

Is there a way I can ensure the event listener only fires once per component? I have tried moving the callback definition into the component's `useEffect` block, and also defining it in `App` and passing it to the component as a prop, but these have all had the same outcome.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: You never remove the listeners in `useEffect` "destructor", but you should

Answer (score 3):

`useEffect` runs twice in dev mode. You have to take care of removing the listeners

```
const create = (id, display) => {
  window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
  window.googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    const slot = window.googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/example', [728, 90], id);
    slot.addService(googletag.pubads());
    window.googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    window.googletag.enableServices();
  });

  const ads = window.googletag.pubads()
  const fn = slotOnloadCallback.bind(null, display)
  ads.addEventListener("slotOnload", fn);

  window.googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    window.googletag.display(id);
  });

  return () => {
    ads.removeEventListener("slotOnload", fn);
  }
}

const Ad = (props) => {
  const { id, display } = props;
  console.log(`Ad ${id}: Rendering`);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Ad ${id}: Mounted`);
    return create(id, display)
  }, []);
  return (
    <div id={id}></div>
  );
};
```